# Compile pymunk on mac OS X

Tags: python, chipmunk, pymunk

I have downloaded pymunk module on my computer. When I typed in "python setup.py install" in terminal, it says "no such file or directory", then I typed in the complete path of setup.py instead of setup.py, and it still could not run since the links to other files in the code of setup.py are not complete paths. (Like README.txt, terminal said "no such file or directory". Sorry I'm a python newbie. Someone tell me how can I fix it?

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and go to the folder where setup.py is first and then do `python setup.py install`. As you have noticed, it assumes that you run it from the same folder as where its located.